# Google maps API crash after too many markers

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-maps, crash

I'm creating a website where I display a dynamic map with a lot of markers. The map works fine when I am using 1100 markers, but it stops working as soon as I add more than that.

The markers are shown and posted in clusters.

It does not return any errors, the map just doesn't display.

I have already tried finding a solution on here but without result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it a Static Map or not?

Comment: No, it is not a static map

Comment: It is the embedded map API

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No errors, the map just doesn't display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API has a rate limit, try slowing down the call with Javascript by setting a timeout like in the example below:

```
wait = true;
setTimeout("wait = true", 5000);
```

Hope this helps!